# How to anonymize (mask) audio (human voice) using javascript

Tags: audio, html5-audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I'm hoping to record the audio of some stories from remote study participants via web browsers. I would like to give them an option of anonymizing their voices before they submit their audio clips. Is there a way to do that in Javascript (or any other library--for example, Python--that I can invoke in the background on the server before serving it back to the participant to verify before they submit?

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJZT6u5SxX0) comes really close to what I would like to accomplish. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and advice!

Comment: What you should probably do is first determine what kind of processing is necessary to reasonably anonymize it. You can slow audio down but if someone decides to speed it back up they will hear the users normal voice.   So what you might want to research is frequency and pitch shifting and then see if these techniques can be used in the language/environment of choice

Comment: @TaoistWA, Thanks! I started looking into pitch shifting. But it'll be a challenge to convert it into javascript module mainly because I lack much experience in signal processing. I'll update again once I make progress. :)

Comment: Apparently it already exist for node. I've never used this but npm is your friend. https://www.npmjs.org/package/soundbank-pitch-shift

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PitchShifter object of [SoundTouchJS](https://github.com/cutterbl/SoundTouchJS) to change the 'key' of the input, and even the playback rate if necessary. It might be helpful to run further convolvers against the AudioNode as well, to futher anonamize it.